# How to estimate the mutual information btw a continuous multidimensional variable and a discrete variable

Tags: machine-learning

all!
I have a deep neural net for a classification task and try to estimate the mutual information btw the output of intermediate layers which should be a multidimensional continuous variable and the corresponding label which is a discrete random variable with single dimension (the distribution of the labels can be estimated from the dataset right?) . Do you know any off-the-shelf packages that can incorporate priors about the distributions of the labels to estimate the mutual information? THANKS~

Comment: hi! Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the how to ask part. 
"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.